# Installing Sametime 8.5 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ibm

Might sound like a familiar question, but could not find an answer yet.

I am trying to install an older version of Sametime (Sametime 8.5) in Ubuntu. The reason for installing an older version is that I could not find a free download of Sametime 9.x.

When I try to install, I get the following missing libraries:

```
Depends: libxt6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libxkbfile1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libstdc++6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
```

Looks like Ubuntu 16.04 already has a newer version of these files. 
So what is the remedy here?

Edit: I found the latest version of Sametime along with instructions
http://insane-on-linux.blogspot.com/2016/10/installing-lotus-notes-90-on-ubuntu-1604.html

Comment: You can try to explicitly install the missing libraries by running `sudo apt install libxt6:i386 libxkbfile1:i386 libstdc++6:i386`